# Вычисление разницы во времени, часовой пояс

Tags: время, php, дата

Надо как-то узнать разницу часового пояса относительно московского времени, есть у кого решения?

Comment: с этими разницами лучше не шутить, лучше сразу в БД по гринвичу заносить в формате UNIX, а потом уже распарсить в нужную дату.

Answer (score 1):

Этот пример [отсюда](http://php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-offset-get.php), думаю, вам поможет:

```
function get_timezone_offset($remote_tz, $origin_tz = null) {
    if($origin_tz === null) {
        if(!is_string($origin_tz = date_default_timezone_get())) {
            return false; // A UTC timestamp was returned -- bail out!
        }
    }
    $origin_dtz = new DateTimeZone($origin_tz);
    $remote_dtz = new DateTimeZone($remote_tz);
    $origin_dt = new DateTime("now", $origin_dtz);
    $remote_dt = new DateTime("now", $remote_dtz);
    $offset = $origin_dtz->getOffset($origin_dt) - $remote_dtz->getOffset($remote_dt);
    return $offset;
}
```